# $_POST the name of a div that is clicked

Tags: html, post, get

How would I post the id of a div that is clicked? The goal is to have a user click one of several squares and post the name of that square in the url and reload the page with that new url. Any suggestions?

I tried to use :

```
 <div id="boxone1" onclick="window.location='index.php?name=<? print $_POST['id'] ?  >';" style="cursor:pointer;">
 </div>
```

But that does nothing and wont reload my page

The goal is to have the user be able to click on the divs in a certain order and have that order match up against a predetermined order. But to make it more complicated, each div is given a random color (one of about 10 colors)each time the page reloads. Therefore, it is the colors that color of the divs that will need to match the predetermined password.

Comment: started by doing <a href="index.php?name=<? print $_POST['name'] ?>"></a> where name is the name of the div

Comment: But why not simply put the name of the div in manually? I mean, the a should reside in the div in order for it to be clicked, right?

Comment: @ryno: you should update your question with details of how far you've got and what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of inline javascript such as onclick events, but see a possible answer below (if dynamically producing these divs):

```
<div id="boxone1" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style="">
```

Else you could always just do:

```
<div id="boxone1" onclick="window.location='?name=boxone1'" style="">
```

Comment: this is helpful, but i need it to work with any of the divs that are selected. (boxone1 boxone2 boxone3 boxone4 boxone5 boxtwo1 boxtwo2 boxtwo3 boxtwo4 boxtwo5). Meaning, i cant have each one seperately just posting their own name in the url, it needs to be dynamic based on which the user clicks on

Comment: if the first example is applied to all of your divs then that will be the case - it will go to the url with the id of whichever div is clicked

Comment: @ryno - You mean when you click on a link *within the `div`*, it appends that `div`'s `id` onto the url the `a` sends the browser to? I'm having a hard time following what in the world you're trying to do. And your use of `$_POST` seems incorrect, unless you *do not* want to affect the URL with the value you pass in the request.

Comment: okay thats working, now the next step that needs to  be implemented is to keep track of all of the divs that are clicked. Meaning if a user selects boxone1 then boxone2 then boxtwo4 then boxtwo2, how would i make the url something like: `http://localhost/colorlock/index.php?name=boxone1name=boxone2?name=boxtwo4?name=boxtwo5`

Comment: @ryno - Pass the click to a function which uses `location.search` to detect and create your url, such as `example.com/click.html?names=boxtwo1,boxone4,boxthree6`. You have to detect the `?` and presence of `names` before you use (or append to) `?` in the url.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, yes $_POST was the wrong thing to use. The goal is to have the user be able to click on the divs in a certain order and have that order match up against a predetermined order. But to make it more complicated, each div is given a random color (one of about 10 colors)each time the page reloads. Therefore, it is the colors that color of the divs that will need to match the predetermined password.

Comment: @JaredFarrish could you explain the location.search a bit more?

Comment: @ryno - I think that's probably a separate question dealing with additive series urls based on click events. I think SmokeyPHP answered the question you had.

Comment: he answered the original question then i expanded on what i was asking... ill accept his and ill make a new, more in depth question. Thanks for the help, i hope to see you on the answers of my next question